# asyncio.await fails with TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable coroutine object

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have this code:

```
done, pending = asyncio.wait(
    [a, b],
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

But it fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/.../api.py", line 83, in websockets_handler
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable coroutine object
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, there should be `await` in front of `asyncio.wait` :)

```
done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
    [a, b],
    return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

Comment: I have `await` inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':`, it will complain `syntaxError: 'await': outside function`.  This is very ridiculous.

Comment: @yoonghm You need to create `async def main():` function (the name doesn’t have to be “main”, it’s just a convention), put the async code in it, and then in `if __name__ == ‘__main__’:` you will have `asyncio.run(main())`. asyncio.run is the “magic” function that runs asyncio event loop and schedules the async function on it, and waits until it is finished - so it is basically running asyncio world inside the sync world :) (For other way around - running sync functions from async world - you need to use threadpool or processpool, see `loop.run_in_executor()`).

Comment: Thanks.I found out that later.  However my problem is now in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61291928/how-to-await-a-coroutine-with-an-event-loop  I know about async in C but I find it difficult to comprehend various async feature in Python.  Need to spend some efforts to understand it.