# How to await a coroutine with an event loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio, apscheduler

I have a coroutine that has an event loop. How should I await that coroutine?  I am using Python 3.7.3.

```
# The coroutine
async def main():
    #
    # This code written using apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio.AsyncIOScheduler
    # which has its *event loop* to run scheduled tasks
    # 
    # However, this code will await another coroutine, e.g.,
    # redis = await aioredis.create_redis('/tmp/redis.sock')

    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The code only runs the main event loop created by `asyncio.run()` but not the one by managed by apscheduler.

**Update 1**

However, if change the code to

```
# The coroutine
async def main():
    #
    # This code written using apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio.AsyncIOScheduler
    # which has its *event loop* to run scheduled tasks
    # 
    # However, this code will await another coroutine, e.g.,
    # redis = await aioredis.create_redis('/tmp/redis.sock')

    #try:
    #    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    #except:
    #    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The code runs `main()` once as the event loop managed by apscheduler does not run.

However, if change the code to

```
# The coroutine
async def main():
    #
    # This code written using apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio.AsyncIOScheduler
    # which has its *event loop* to run scheduled tasks
    # 
    # However, this code will await another coroutine, e.g.,
    # redis = await aioredis.create_redis('/tmp/redis.sock')

    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The complains that the coroutine 'main' was never awaited.

Comment: You await it like any other coroutine by using `await`? I'm not sure I'm understanding what you are asking. You might want to clarify what the problem was with what you have tried.